# MATLAB swapping rows with zero in its pivot position, partial pivoting?

Tags: matlab, pivot, gaussian

I want this matrix to turn into

```
A =

     1     2    -1     4     5
     1    -6     7     5     6
     0     0     4     7     5
     0    -3     4     7     7
     1     5     1     5     6
```

This kind of matrix.

```
A =

     1     2    -1     4     5
     1    -6     7     5     6
     1     5     1     5     6
     0    -3     4     7     7
     0     0     4     7     5
```

So, any row with zero in its pivot position should go down.

I was able to find rows with zero in its pivots by using the following code:

```
count=0;
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if A(i,j)~=0
            break
        else
            count=count+1;
            row(count)=i;
            break
        end
    end
end
row

>> row =

    3     4
```

But I don't know how I can proceed after this point. I want to make a code that applies to any kind of matrix. Plz help.

Comment: Why can't you add an extra column in the end which indicates number of zeros in the row and then `sortrows` based on that column ? Do the position of the zeros also matter ? Rather than showing an example could you explain what you are fundamentally trying to do ?

Comment: What if 1st column of two rows is same but second column of  one of them is zero? Will now the sorting depend on second column?

Comment: @SomeGuy that won't be a good option, because if a row is like [0 0 4 5 1 0 4], then there are three zeros, but one of them is not in the pivot position. So I need a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
A =[1     2    -1     4     5;
    1    -6     7     5     6;
    0     0     4     7     5;
    0    -3     4     7     7;
    1     5     1     5     6];
% find the last zero in each row
[val,lastZeroIdx] = min(A == 0,[],2);
% find rows which their first column is zero
c = A(:,1) == 0;
% eliminate rows which their first column isn't zero
lastZeroIdx(~c) = 0;
% sort by the location of the last zeros
[~,rowsIdx] = sort(lastZeroIdx,'ascend');
% rearrange A
B = A(rowsIdx,:)
```

and you get:

```
B = [1     2    -1     4     5
     1    -6     7     5     6
     1     5     1     5     6
     0    -3     4     7     7
     0     0     4     7     5]
```